# Security concerns AspNetCore Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

we are currently making an online scheduler for our customers using clientside Blazor (hosted) with AspNetCore Identity on top of it for security. We pretty much sticked to the default implementation (for the most part) of the tool. The application has a somewhat simple Client-Server architecture with the client, webapi, data access layer and the database behind that.

Now, the application is running on a database user solely created for this purpose which is provided in the connection-string in the appsettings of the server-project. Since I've mostly written Intranet applications until now, I'm wondering if there are any security concerns in the above mentioned structure of the project I should be aware of?

Is there any way of a user bypassing the application security and using the token to gain database access and/or access the database? If so, how and how can I prevent that?

The Startup class:

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(services =>
        {
            services.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultDatabase"), sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60));
        });

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>();

        services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, CustomUserStore>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, DatabaseContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddSwaggerDocument();
        services.AddApplication();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            app.UseSwaggerUi3();
            app.UseOpenApi();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
```

Feel free to ask for more details if required. Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: no, there's absolutely no way and it would be a nightmare of a framework that nobody would ever use if that was even remotely possible.

Comment: "Security" is a concept that reaches much further than just "is my DB connection string secure". Based on that little info about your whole setup there's nothing obviously flawed about it, no. In any case, if you want a security review of your application, I suggest you contact some experts instead of leaning on StackOverflow

Comment: @srole Can you provide more details about your architecture? you mentioned using WASM but can you explain if you have IDS4 setup on your client app as well? if yes why is that? When it comes to security nothing is 100% secure but following best practices and having proper design in place helps alot